# Looking to color code with two if condition in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am looking to color code field with two if condition, Have tried the below code,

```
If(
   ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Imperial") 
   Or ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Metric")  
   && Value('Output'.Text) > 80,360, 
     RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ), 
     RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color when either "Imperial" or "Metric" is selected for User Input - Unit AND output value is greater than 80360, try using below formula:

```
If(
    Or('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Imperial", 'User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Metric") && Value('Output'.Text) > 80360,
    RGBA(220, 20, 60, 1),
    RGBA(127, 255, 212, 1)
)
```

**Microsoft Documentation**: [And, Or, and Not functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-logicals)

---

**Update from comments**:

Try using this formula:

```
If(
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Imperial" && Value('Output'.Text) > 80) || ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Metric" && Value('Output'.Text) > 360),
    RGBA(220, 20, 60, 1),
    RGBA(127, 255, 212, 1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to execute both if condition i.e "Imerial/Metric" and "80/360" .

Comment: I have updated my answer, check and try the new formula.

Comment: Working good, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your formula has a number in the last condition with a thousand separator ( 80,360 ). The comma separator collides with the the Power Apps expression language, since it already reserved comma to separate function arguments.

```
If( ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Imperial") Or ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "Metric") && Value('Output'.Text) > 80360, RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ), RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my case is if "Imperial" is selected and the value exceeds 80 it should fill with color as mentioned and if "Metric" is selected and the value exceeds 360 the same follows.